# How to import CSV file into TDengine database

Tags: tdengine

I have a CSV file and I want to import my data into the TDengine database. Are there any tutorials for data importing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following sql:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name FILE '/tmp/csvfile.csv';

INSERT INTO table_name USING super_table_name TAGS ('Beijing.Chaoyang', 2) FILE '/tmp/csvfile.csv';

INSERT INTO table_name_1 USING super_table_name TAGS ('Beijing.Chaoyang', 2) FILE '/tmp/csvfile_21001.csv'
            table_name_2 USING super_table_name (groupId) TAGS (2) FILE '/tmp/csvfile_21002.csv';
```

you can find more details from here [Taos SQL](https://www.taosdata.com/cn/documentation/taos-sql)